# How to view all logged user in mysql yog?

Tags: mysql

I want to see all loggin username in current local system in my sql Database using tool for SQL Yog.

Comment: Did you do any research on this, or did you just ask here in the hope someone will do the research for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 5.5+, you can run this query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) LoginCount,user UserName
FROM informtion_schema.processlist
WHERE user <> 'system user'
GROUP BY user;
```

This will give you how many live (active) DB Connection a user has.

Give it a Try !!!